# How to monitor memory usage for alarming purpose

Tags: linux, memory

We have embedded Linux system without swap.

Currenly we must raise alarm when memory usage % increases over a threashold.
And reboot when memory usage % increases over a (higher) threshold.

Why we want to do that: If some program leaks, we can do safety reboot, before kernel start killing our processes (which may lead to data corruption or unavailability).

But we have a problem:

**How to count memory usage-% which can be used for our purpose?**

We tried to count memory usage by using values of /proc/meminfo:

```
/ # cat /proc/meminfo
MemTotal:       126744 kB
MemFree:         58256 kB
Buffers:         16740 kB
Cached:          31308 kB
SwapCached:          0 kB
Active:          37580 kB
Inactive:        24000 kB
```

Without success:

`(MemTotal - MemFree)` is not usable, because it contains for example caches.

`(MemTotal - MemFree - Buffers - Cached)` did ignore effect of `Inactive`. So it also gives too big memory usage values.

`(MemTotal - MemFree - Buffers - Cached - Inactive)` is unusable, because result can be negative.

Answer (score 6):

**Monitor system via `free`**

```
[root@localhost ~]# free
          total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:    2058240    1776788     281452          0      89780    1335840
-/+ buffers/cache:  351168    1707072
Swap:   4095992        100    4095892
```

Look at the `-/+ buffers/cache` line `used` and `free`

**Monitor each process via /proc**

I used this python script and /proc/pid/stat to monitor the memory of a process:

http://phacker.org/2009/02/20/monitoring-virtual-memory-usage-with-python/

you would probably like to translate something like this to c.

**Limit resource for each process**

or use `ulimit` / `setrlimit`

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4983120/limit-memory-usage-for-a-single-linux-process

Comment: Can you explain the method your Python script uses to calculate the memory usage? That would make this a much better answer.

Comment: Well, it just logs the vm-usage in steps of a second. I used that for graphing the mem consumption over program lifetime. This was handy to debug mem leaks in long running programms.

Comment: You could just use this to monitor a prog after some init time. And alert some "leak suspect flag" if vmusage crosses certain treshold.

Comment: The link to phacker.org is no more

Comment: ...which is why StarckExchange always asks to post the contents of scripts, not just links

Answer (score 5):

```
#!/bin/bash

threshold=90
threshold2=95

freemem=$(($(free -m |awk 'NR==2 {print $3}') * 100))

usage=$(($freemem / 512))

if [ "$usage" -gt "$threshold" ]

then

/etc/init.d/service_name restart

     if [ "$usage" -gt "$threshold2" ]

     then

     echo "The memory usage has reached $usage% on $HOSTNAME." | mail -s "High Memory Usage Alert" admin@domain.com


     fi
fi
```

Name this as alert.sh and execute the command: `chmod +x alert.sh`

Configure a cron to run this script every 10 minutes

Make sure to replace '512' with your server total memory in MB and 'admin@domain.com' with actual email address. This will send an email alert whenever memory usage goes beyond 95 % and will restart the service "service_name" if it reaches 90%

Answer (score 2):

You can use a shell script in cron with the free command to monitor the memory and act acording its values. For example, to monitor RAM memory:

```
#!/bin/bash

LOG_DIR=/var/log/memory_monitor.log

DATE=$(date +%d/%m/%Y)
TIME=$(date +%H:%M)
TIMESTAMP="$DATE $TIME"

MONITOR=$(free | grep Mem)
MEM_USED=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $3 }')
MEM_FREE=$(echo $MONITOR | awk '{ print $4 }')

echo "$TIMESTAMP $MEM_USED $MEM_FREE" >> $LOG_DIR
```

Instead of echoing the output, you could eval the values to the limits you want and mail, reboot or whatever action you want:

```
if [ eval_values > threshold ]
then
    # Do stuff (mail, reboot, etc)
fi
```

Then you add it to crontab to be run in the intervals you want.

Answer (score 1):

another useful utility from the sysstat package is sar.

For memory information, use:

```
$ sar -r 1
Linux 3.0.0-12-generic (HFC-2600)       05/03/2012      _i686_  (4 CPU)

01:35:45 PM kbmemfree kbmemused  %memused kbbuffers  kbcached  kbcommit   %commit  kbactive   kbinact
01:35:46 PM    118484    907364     88.45     59200    317368   2169716    104.75    412476    436140
```

I could definitely use more RAM on this box.