# What are valid reasons to monitor MemFree or Active as opposed to MemUsable?

Tags: linux, memory, monitoring

[How to monitor memory usage for alarming purpose](https://superuser.com/questions/419617/how-to-monitor-memory-usage-for-alarming-purpose) talks about the reasons to use MemUsable as the proper metric for alarming on memory, however I still see a lot of instances of alarming on Active or MemFree.  What are some reasons that you'd want to monitor these metrics in addition to or instead of MemUsable?